# Why are my data model values undefined after data is stoed in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm building a notes app, fetching data from a local api that I made.
Thing is, when I load data into my NoteModel in my component, values under the second "level" of models are undefined.

The data comes as a `JSON` obviously, that I want to save into my Model:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "note": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Test1",
                "description": "Testing testing",
                "completed": false
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Test2",
                "description": "Testing testing",
                "completed": false
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Test3",
                "description": "Testing testing",
                "completed": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my `NoteModel`

```js
import { NoteContent } from "./note-content-model"

export interface NoteModel {
    Id: number;
    NoteContent: NoteContent[];
}
```

And this is my `NoteContent` model:

```js
export interface NoteContent {
    Id: number;
    Title: string;
    Description: string;
    Completed: boolean;
}
```

As I understand it, it should load everything into both models when I save the `JSON` into the model object, as I try in my `home.component.ts`, that should load my list of components

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NoteService } from '../services/note.service';
import { NoteModel } from '../note-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  notes?: NoteModel;

  constructor(private noteService: NoteService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.noteService.getNotes()
      .subscribe(response => {
        if (response.length >= 0) {
          this.notes = response[0];
          console.log(this.notes.NoteContent)
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Then I try to get the stored data in my html component using `ngFor` but I dont get anything.

Comment: cammel case in your interface?

Comment: Is it bad? @cuongle

Comment: Edit your Question, and please mention your NoteService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interfaces have properties that are named in PascalCase.
The received JSON has properties that are named in cammelCase.

Equally important is that your received JSON has a property name `note`, but in your `NoteModel` interface you named the property `NoteContent`.

Replace your interfaces with the following and your code should work.

```
export interface NoteModel {
  id: number;
  note: NoteContent[];
}

export interface NoteContent {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Bruh I never imagined it would matter for my JSON to match the casing of  my models, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case sensitive. 'title' and 'Title' are different things. You need to unify your model and the json